# How to disable the charge indicator on the GS7 lock screen

Tags: lock-screens

I'm getting a charge indicator on my Galaxy S7 lock lock screen.  When the screen blanks I have to go through and extra step to get to the home screen.  It has a new step with white fonts on a blue screen.

The writings are:

> **Full Charged Left
>
>   Speed Continue Trickle**

At the bottom of the screen it says:

> **Slide to unlock**

Does anyone know what app is causing this screen to come up and how to disable it?

Comment: @beeshyams The purpose of the factory reset is for diagnosis of the issue.  It's  away to ensure third party program are not the culprit, and as you mentioned, identify that the OS is the culprit.  I'm in analysis mode to identify the culprit while I continue to figure out how to deal with it.  Flashing the ROM on questions isn't the first thing a novice should consider.  Flashing the ROM could cause a personal to loose support form the Manufacturer as well as their carrier for other the immediate problems as well as others that might arise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38533/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-l-d-james).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is a feature of the [GO Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex).  It has the appearance if being a default function of the phone's OS.  The screen has one option in the menu:  `turn off fast charging`.  That will disable that screen, but it won't disable the Samsung GS(x)'s fast charging.  You can enable or disable the GS7's fast charging in the Settings menu of the device (not the `Go` program)

Turning that switch on the screen disabled the extra step (having to slide) before you get to your actual unlock screen where you put in your code.

This screen will manifest itself on any Android phone or tablet running the `Go Launcher` menu app.

Comment: great! Finally I got rid of all advertisements and the extra action to unlock my phone. Thanks